# How do I render a handlebars layout in node.js from a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js

This is a really weird issue I am having.

I have a login form, this login form verifies your data and renders the Profile layout if the login is successful OR renders the register page if the login is not.

```
exports.logIn = function (req, res, data) {
  var username = req.body.username.toString();
  var password = req.body.password.toString();
  connection.connection();
  global.connection.query('SELECT * FROM Utilizador WHERE Nome_Utilizador = ? LIMIT 1', [username], function (err, result) {

if (result.length > 0) {
  if (result) {
    var object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    var userObject = object[0];
    var userQ = object[0].Nome_Utilizador;
    global.connection.query('SELECT Password_Utilizador from Utilizador where Nome_Utilizador = ?', [username], function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.length > 0) {
        if (result) {
          var object2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
          var passQ = object[0].Password_Utilizador;
          if (password == passQ) {
            console.log("Login efectuado com sucesso");
            console.log(userObject);
            res.render('home', { title: 'perfil', layout: 'perfil', data: userObject });
          } else {
            console.log("1");
          }
        }
      } else if (err) {
        console.log("asdsadas");
      } else {
        console.log("2");
        res.render('home', { title: 'perfil', layout: 'registo' });
      }
    });
  }
} else if (err) {
  console.log(err);

} else {
  console.log("Utilizador nao encontrado");
  res.render('home', { title: 'perfil', layout: 'registo' });
}
});
};
```

This works.

And the only reason why it does work is because it comes from a FORM with a METHOD and an ACTION

```
<form id="login-nav" action="/login" method='POST' role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username" class="sr-only">Utilizador</label>
                  <input id="username" type="username" placeholder="Nome de utilizador" required="" class="form-control" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword2" class="sr-only">Palavra-Passe</label>
                  <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Meta a palavra-passe" required="" class="form-control" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label></label>
                  <input type="checkbox">Gravar Dados
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button id="botaoLogin" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Fazer Login</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

However, I tried to do the same thing with jQuery, as I need to render a Handlebars layout for some products on button click,

```
$("#pacotes").on('click', ".produto", function () {
    var prod = this.id;
    console.log(prod);
    $.get("http://localhost:3000/pacote?idPacote=" + prod);
});
```

And despite the query working and giving me the [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbxVy.png) I requested

```
exports.Pacote = function (req, res) {
  var pacote = req.query.idPacote;
  connection.connection();
  global.connection.query('SELECT * FROM Pacotes WHERE idPacotes = ? ', [pacote], function (err, result) {
     if (result.length > 0) {
       if (result) {
         var object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
         var packObject = object[0];
         console.log(result);
         res.render('home', { title: 'pacote', layout: 'pacote', data: packObject });
     } else if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
   };
 });
}
```

It simply doesn't render the layout and I have no idea why.
What is the difference between doing a POST request like this or doing it by a form?

I don't understand why this only seems to work with forms.
I could solve it that way, but I don't think using empty forms for all my buttons would be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are only making a request, you are not processing the return value:

`$.get("http://localhost:3000/pacote?idPacote=" + prod);`

Try changing to something like:

`$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: "http://localhost:3000/pacote?idPacote=" + prod,
  success: function(...) {...}
});`